# UK Border Landing Card lower case

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

What happens if you fill the landing card with lowercase letters as normal but neatly?

Is it a problem because it says BLOCK letters. In one visit to UK I filled with lower case letters in the plane an when I read Block Letters I was worried about them not letting me in. So I filled another form and disposed the previous one.

What would have happened if I had tried to give the lower case one?

Comment: It's hypothetical. There's no references to it in the operations manual. Overall it's best not to come across as a smart ass, but there's no definitive answer to your question. Mileage varies. Close voting as "opinion-based", sorry.

Comment: Probably nothing. Pretty sure I've gone through the UK border with a lowercase landing card. My guess it that they only say that because writing in all caps is generally easier to read.

Comment: Is block letters 'all caps' or is BLOCK the indication all caps is wanted. (For me it is almost impossible to do all caps, not and still be readable.) This is the reason I voted to keep open.

Comment: Google image search suggests that the instruction is "BLOCK CAPITALS", which is different than "block letters".  The latter just means not in cursive.  For what it's worth, I've filled out the landing card not in all caps and never been asked about it, but I guess the real answer is "try to remember to follow the instructions."

Comment: @Louis It cannot be cursive and lowercase.You think like writing one by one clearly.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, both the official and your personal experience.

Comment: @Willeke, You are welcome .I thought it was a hesitation any one can experience of.

Comment: It is dyslectia in my case, no cursive/running script nor 'all caps' or 'all lower case', that is just the way it works.

Comment: It might depend on the official, and whether the official is having a bad day or not.

Comment: So that, when scanned and using Optical Character Recognition (OCR), the text is analyzed and turned into a form that a computer can process..

Answer (score 4):

I can't find an image of the landing card on gov.uk, but Google image search turns up lots of ones [like this](http://sean.kiev.ua/img/landing_card_small.jpg), where the instruction is "BLOCK CAPITALS".  This is different than "[block letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_letters)", which can include lower case (what Americans call "printing" as opposed to "cursive").

The "real" answer has to be that you should follow the directions.

As a practical matter, I have to fill this landing card out fairly frequently, and I've definitely forgotten and used lower case letters on occasion.  Nobody has ever asked me about it.  My usual handwriting is fairly clear printing.